# static variable for request count in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my `routes.php` I have a debug filter like so:

```
Route::filter('debug', function() {
  if(App::environment() !== 'dev') { return; }

  error_log("\n\n\n\n REQUEST NO. " . $staticRequestCount++ . "\n\n");

  // log the request headers
  // log the request body
```

I'm a noob in both php and laravel. Is it possible to create a static `requestCount` varaible as above which keep increasing all the time until you restart the server (or similar) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php, its not possible to share a variable across different requests without using a external storage support. Each request will be a separate process or thread according to the apache worker implementation. So the code wont be able to share a common variable in memory to serve as a counter.

You can do it by writing the counter values on to a cache. Check out [`APC`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or [`memcached`](http://memcached.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. You cannot detect if server was restarted using PHP. But you can simple save such counter into file and read it from file each time you run your filter, increase it and save modified value but of course it won't be automatically deleted (or set to 0) if server will be restarted.